# How to write this VBA code shorter/neater

Tags: excel, vba

I have been having a hard time writing this in a much shorter way, i know its probably simple, but i cant get my head around having nested ifs while the range changes , any suggestions?

The data is in 7 columns , Sun to Sat
Basically I need to figure out what day the report has data up to from M3:Sx , so currently i am assuming its a full week and then working backwards to check for no data.

Some days may be blank  in between so Sunday may have data and then no data until Thursday , so I need iDayNumber to be 5 in this case

```
iDayNumber = 7

   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("S" & iFirstRow & ":S" & iLastRow)) = 0 Then
      iDayNumber = iDayNumber - 1

      If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("R" & iFirstRow & ":R" & iLastRow)) = 0 Then
         iDayNumber = iDayNumber - 1

          If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("Q" & iFirstRow & ":Q" & iLastRow)) = 0 Then
             iDayNumber = iDayNumber - 1

             If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("P" & iFirstRow & ":P" & iLastRow)) = 0 Then
                iDayNumber = iDayNumber - 1

                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("O" & iFirstRow & ":O" & iLastRow)) = 0 Then
                   iDayNumber = iDayNumber - 1

                   If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("N" & iFirstRow & ":N" & iLastRow)) = 0 Then                      
                       iDayNumber = iDayNumber - 1

                      If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("M" & iFirstRow & ":M" & iLastRow)) = 0 Then

                        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                        If MsgBox("There is no data in the current week." & vbCrLf & "Cannot Continue.", _
                           vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Aborting") = vbOK Then

                           Exit Sub

                          End If
                       End If
                     End If
                   End If
                 End If
               End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use a for loop with the Offset function

```
 For i = 6 To 0 Step -1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("M" & iFirstRow & ":M" & iLastRow).Offset(0, i)) = 0 Then
        iDayNumber = iDayNumber - 1
    Else
        Exit For
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: i need to step to the left , how to write a loop in a minus? thanks!

Comment: Sorry I just notified my error I will correct my answer

Comment: no i need to start at 7 and work down,  have to start with s( latest data on the right)

Comment: (M:M).Offset(0,6) = (S:S)

Comment: thanks! i should take a break after this stupidity :0